# qrcode-vue3 CORS issue intermittently

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I am using this package - [qrcode-vue3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-vue3) in my Laravel Vue project.

I am creating a QR code in various places of the app, each of which contains an logo image supplied via the component options:

```
<template>
    <QRCodeVue3
        v-bind="qrOptions"
    />
</template>

<script>
import QRCodeVue3 from "qrcode-vue3";
import {computed} from "vue";
import {useStore} from "vuex";

export default {
    name: "QrGenerator",
    components: {
        QRCodeVue3,
    },
    props: {
        qrData: {
            type: String,
            default: undefined,
        },
        withSquareLogo: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        width: {
            type: Number,
            default: 300,
        },
        height: {
            type: Number,
            default: 300,
        },
        download: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        downloadFileName: {
            type: String,
            default: undefined,
        },
    },
    setup(props) {
        const store = useStore();

        const colors = computed(() => store.getters['whiteLabel/colors']);
        const logos = computed(() => store.getters['whiteLabel/logos']);

        const qrOptions = computed( () => ({
            "backgroundOptions": {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            },
            "backgroundOptionsHelper": {
                "colorType": {
                    "gradient": false,
                    "single": true
                },
                "gradient": {
                    "color1": "#ffffff",
                    "color2": "#ffffff",
                    "linear": true,
                    "radial": false,
                    "rotation": "0"
                }
            },
            "cornersDotOptions": {
                "color": "#000000",
                "type": ""
            },
            "cornersDotOptionsHelper": {
                "colorType": {
                    "gradient": false,
                    "single": true
                },
                "gradient": {
                    "color1": "#000000",
                    "color2": "#000000",
                    "linear": true,
                    "radial": false,
                    "rotation": "0"
                }
            },
            "cornersSquareOptions": {
                "color": "#000000",
                "type": "extra-rounded"
            },
            "cornersSquareOptionsHelper": {
                "colorType": {
                    "gradient": false,
                    "single": true
                },
                "gradient": {
                    "color1": "#000000",
                    "color2": "#000000",
                    "linear": true,
                    "radial": false,
                    "rotation": "0"
                }
            },
            "value": props.qrData,
            "dotsOptions": {
                "color": colors.value.primary_color,
                "type": "extra-rounded"
            },
            "dotsOptionsHelper": {
                "colorType": {
                    "gradient": false,
                    "single": true
                },
                "gradient": {
                    "color1": colors.value.primary_color,
                    "color2": colors.value.primary_color,
                    "linear": true,
                    "radial": false,
                    "rotation": "0"
                }
            },
            "image": logos.value.square,
            "imageOptions": {
                "hideBackgroundDots": true,
                "imageSize": 0.4,
                "margin": 0,
                "crossOrigin": "Anonymous"
            },
            "margin": 0,
            "qrOptions": {
                "errorCorrectionLevel": "Q",
                "mode": "Byte",
                "typeNumber": "0"
            },
            "download": false,
            "height": props.height,
            "width": props.width
        }));

        return {
            logos,
            colors,
            qrOptions,
        }
    }
};
```

This works OK for some of the time, with logo loading into the QR code. The logo is in a static assets S3 bucket, that is public access and allow-origins of "*". The domain to the static assets bucket (https://static.myapp.com.au) is being proxied via CloudFlare.

But for some of the time I get a CORS error as the component is mounting and generating the QR:

```
Access to image at 'https://static.myapp.com.au/logo_square.png' from origin 'https://lins.myapp.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  index.js?f95a:1          
GET https://static.myapp.com.au/logo_square.png net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

It has wasted a bunch of time now but without luck in finding the solution. It will work consecutively for a number of tries (say 20 times), then try again some minutes later and Bang! CORS error.

Thanks

Comment: Same endpoint? Double check your network tab. Maybe some token is expiring after a minute or so.

Comment: Hi Kissu. Same endpoint. Weirdly it works for some 20+ consecutive page loads then the cors issue for a few more.